# linux etc services - how to define the process port number

Tags: linux, operating-system

I have created 4 Jboss Karaf containers, and want to dedicate the port assignments. I'm confused with how to edit the services file, in that the first field the process name, which it is called from.  can this be a dummy name or does it need to be a real name of a process using port?

example what I'd like to do. I don't know if I even need to be concerned with this.
I did ensure these ports are not in use by any other process running on machine. And they are declared in the application configurations.

```
# application container port assignments for clustered environments
# Fleet Container
rmiServerPort   44441/tcp               # clustered IPRC Fleet Container
rmiServerPort   44441/udp               # clustered IPRC Fleet Container
activemqPort    61616/tcp               #
activemqPort    61616/udp               #
# PassThru Container
rmiServerPort   44442/tcp               # clustered PassThru Container
rmiServerPort   44442/udp               # clustered PassThru Container
activemqPort    61617/tcp               #
activemqPort    61617/udp               #
# Fadec Container
rmiServerPort   44443/tcp               # clustered fadec Container
rmiServerPort   44443/udp               # clustered fadec Container
activemqPort    61618/tcp               #
activemqPort    61618/udp               #
# MRO Container
rmiServerPort   44445/tcp               # clustered MRO Container
rmiServerPort   44445/udp               # clustered MRO Container
activemqPort    61622/tcp               #
activemqPort    61622/udp               #
```